# -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I used one tutorial to include My twitter home page in my code, but for me does not works.

This is the code

```
  @implementation VSViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad
          {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self twitterTimeline];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

      - (void)twitterTimeline {

ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]; // Creates AccountStore object.

// Asks for the Twitter accounts configured on the device.

ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     // If we have access to the Twitter accounts configured on the device we will contact the Twitter API.

     if (granted == YES){


         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType]; // Retrieves an array of Twitter accounts configured on the device.

         // If there is a leat one account we will contact the Twitter API.

         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {

             ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject]; // Sets the last account on the device to the twitterAccount variable.

             NSURL *requestAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"]; // API call that returns entires in a user's timeline.

             // The requestAPI requires us to tell it how much data to return so we use a NSDictionary to set the 'count'.

             NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

             [parameters setObject:@"100" forKey:@"count"];

             [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

             // This is where we are getting the data using SLRequest.

             SLRequest *posts = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestAPI parameters:parameters];

             posts.account = twitterAccount;

             // The postRequest: method call now accesses the NSData object returned.

             [posts performRequestWithHandler:

              ^(NSData *response, NSHTTPURLResponse
                *urlResponse, NSError *error)
              {
                  // The NSJSONSerialization class is then used to parse the data returned and assign it to our array.

                  self.array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                  if (self.array.count != 0) {

                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                          [self.tableView reloadData]; // Here we tell the table view to reload the data it just recieved.

                      });

                  }

              }];

         }

     } else {

         // Handle failure to get account access
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

     }

        }];

       }

    #pragma mark Table View Data Source Mehtods

   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section        {

// Returns the number of rows for the table view using the array instance variable.

return [_array count];

      }

      -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Creates each cell for the table view.

static NSString *cellID =  @"CELLID" ;

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

}

   // Creates an NSDictionary that holds the user's posts and then loads the data into each cell of the table view.
```

IT CRASHES HERE with the error -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
NSDictionary *tweet = _array[indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = tweet[@"text"];

return cell;
     }
```

Comment: that is why the accessor part of the literal syntax is voodoo... call me a curmudgeon, but I never use it... I like the literal constructor syntax.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that `_array` is not an array (it's a dictionary).

You only have to read the error message to see this.

You can't make any assumptions about what kind of object `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` will give you; it depends on what the JSON data looks like. In this case, the JSON structure has resulted in the Objective-C equivalent being an NSDictionary. The fact that you may have *called* your `array` instance variable an NSArray makes no difference; in Objective-C, an object is what it is (polymorphism).

You didn't catch the problem earlier because `count` is a method both of NSDictionary and of NSArray, so you didn't crash when you said `self.array.count`.